# Installing vs implementing SSL and do I need to set up redirects after installing SSL?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I have a Wordpress blog on a Bluehost server and now want to start selling something through Gumroad (from a pop-up directly from my site), for which I need an SSL certificate.

I already bought the SSL certificate from Bluehost and they say it's now 'installed' and told me to change the url on a working page to https:// to double check and thats working fine.

What I'm really confused about is this: Since the https:// already seems to be working, does that mean that my entire website has now been duplicated and I need to set up redirects from http:// to https:// to avoid Google penalties?

I only really wanted to use https:// for the sales page of my product which isn't set up yet. I thought I still had to implement the SSL certificate through a plugin like the Wordpress HTTPs plugin and would be able to do so only for that single page, leaving the rest of the website as is.

All of my inbound and outbound links are http://, so I'm a little worried now. Could someone clear this up for me?

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10283278/1709033)

Comment: possible duplicate of [http https dupliacte content google](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10283217/http-https-dupliacte-content-google)